# filter only sublocalities in google maps api

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I want to get nearby sublocalities in google maps api

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');         
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        types: ["geocode"]
    });
```

This adds autocomplete for all places being typed in the text box. I want to filter out only the sublocalities and get the nearby sub localities in the autocomplete

Check the working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/kLy356z5/)

Comment: Does `types: ["(cities)"]` give you want you are looking for?  From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompletionRequest) "types | Type:  Array<string> | The types of predictions to be returned. Four types are supported: 'establishment' for businesses, 'geocode' for addresses, '(regions)' for administrative regions and **'(cities)' for localities**. If nothing is specified, all types are returned."

Comment: Thanks, this partially answers as its able to filter out sublocations. I will post getting nearby locations as a different question and edit this question.  Please post this as answer if its okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types: ["(cities)"] will give you just localities.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions) :

> **"types** | Type: Array | The types of predictions to be returned. Four types are supported: 'establishment' for businesses, 'geocode' for addresses, '(regions)' for administrative regions and **'(cities)' for localities**. If nothing is specified, all types are returned."

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');         
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
    types: ["(cities)"]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar usecase too. I did not have a way to do it using google maps api. But, you can try getting geometry (lat, lng) from Autocomplete getPlaces() and use geonames.org API to get nearby sublocalities giving lat, lng and radius

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=13.041703&lng=80.251943&radius=5&username=demo